# How to improve the SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I have queries like below (intended for same result) and I want to optimize the query so that it reduces CPU usage of database server.

I have tried two different queries below and it seems that two queries have similar performance. (checked using `SHOW PROFILES`)

Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

**Information:**

```
Table A has 7333 rows    
Table B has 5656 rows    
Table C has 1108 rows    
Table D has ~150 rows (keep changing)    
Table E has 18576 rows
```

**Query1:**

```
SELECT A.ct, A.res, A.ctype, A.cweight, B.lat, B.lng, C.first, C.second, C.third
FROM A
JOIN B
ON A.ct= B.dct
JOIN C
ON A.ct = C.dct
LEFT JOIN 
( 
SELECT D.dct
FROM D
JOIN E
ON D.oct = E.oct
WHERE E.oct is null
OR (E.oct is not null 
AND E.wua <> '')
) as K
ON A.ct = K.dct
WHERE A.type = 1 AND B.lng != '' AND B.lat != '' AND A.black != 1 AND B.modi_time > (NOW() + INTERVAL 8 HOUR) 
ORDER BY A.ct DESC
```

**Query2:**

```
SELECT A.ct, A.res, A.ctype, A.cweight, B.lat, B.lng, C.first, C.second, C.third
FROM A 
JOIN B 
ON A.ct = B.ct
JOIN C 
ON A.ct = C.dct
WHERE A.type = 1 AND B.lng != '' AND B.lat != '' AND A.black != 1 AND B.modi_time > (NOW() + INTERVAL 8 HOUR) 
AND A.ct NOT IN ( 
SELECT D.dct
FROM D 
JOIN E
ON D.oct = E.oct
WHERE E.wua <> ''
)
ORDER BY A.ct DESC;
```

Comment: The first query - the problem could be the OR condition. The second query - I would rewirite NOT IN with NOT EXISTS. Of course you need to check indexes (e.wua) and execution plans.

Comment: Use UNION instead of OR. NOT IN should be avoided.

Comment: indexing should be done on all the equating fields and only on indexed fields, equating should be there, otherwise it will end with table scan only.

Comment: Please read this, especially the part on query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/  Then [edit] your question.

Comment: I believe the first query is returning the same result even without subquery behind LEFT JOIN. Therefore they are not equivalent queries.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT... )` and `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` have different semantics.  What (in English) do you hope to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience,
try to declare a variable for the value ( NOW() + INTERVAL 8 HOUR ) then use the variable in the query like:

```
AND B.modi_time>@variable
```

this might enhance your query performance.